# Essay Formatting Question: Use of examples

Tags: academia, style-manuals

Good day everyone;

I hope I have signed up to the right forum because I am conflicted on a formatting issue.  As of now, I am writing an essay for one of my classes in the APA format.  Just for background, my paper is double-spaced, 12 point font, etc. the basics.

Essentially, I have two questions:
1) When you quote an example that is longer than a couple of lines, is it appropriate to indent it and bring it to size 10 font?
For example:

Blah blah blah blah blah blah blay; Bob(2008), an astrophysicist from the University of Boston, gives a perfect example:

```
       "blah blah blah blah blah blah" [imagine this part is in 10 font]
```

2) If the first question is: yes, it is appropriate, then: is it appropriate to do that with your own examples?  Examples that you, yourself have made?

Thank you for any help you can provide :)

Comment: No, this isn't the right site. Try [writers.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not in the scope of our site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APA cutoff for quotations is 40 words. When that threshold is exceeded, use block as opposed to in-line quotation format. (In-line is the kind with the quotation marks.) For typography, the APA manual (6th ed., section 6.03, p. 171) says merely to indent the block about half an inch from the left, same as for the first line of a regular text paragraph, and to double-space vertically, which is no change from the surrounding text. There is nothing about shrinking font size.

In general, for both APA and MLA styles, it is common for a journal to use a smaller font for block quotations and to inset the block symmetrically, so that the right margin moves in just as the left one does. But that is for the article or paper as finally *printed.* Most editors and professors still positively prefer that the double-spaced manuscript version be prepared and submitted without such typographic niceties even attempted.

I am afraid I find no entry for “examples” in the index to the APA manual.

Comment: An established user like yourself should know not to answer blatantly off topic questions.

Comment: Thank you @Brian Donovan for answering my question, even though I posted mistakenly in the wrong forum.  You are of great help :).  I tip my hat off to you!

Comment: Finally, thank you @curiousdannii for pointing me to the correct forum for future reference.

Comment: My logic when I read the rules was that word usage includes anything relating to how a word is used.  In this case it was many words and how they must be used in relation to a format.